# Building a complete application (design, languages, and database)

Tags: web-applications, architecture

I have an idea to create a review application (back-end and multiple front-end) and I am struggling with which direction to take.

For context, let’s say that the application would be something like Yelp.com, users would post reviews (to a product) and then read other users' reviews.

Basically, my main idea would be to create an API based back-end, and once that is done, I would then build (or have them built) a website and mobile apps (Android/iOS) to consume the API which would retrieve and post data. Also please keep in mind that this application would also consume (read only) other external API’s.

For the next questions, please think about hosting as well. In the beginning, I will probably stick to regular Linux hosting, then move up to dedicated as we grow. 
Also, this is my “home” project, so there is not a lot of money to be put into it, except my time, of course.

Questions:

1) Design:

Is this really the best approach? Yeah, I would love to create something great from the ground up, but should I be worried with that from the beginning? Or, should I take a simpler approach – no API, just website & mobile apps querying and posting data directly – and then go crazy once we become Yelp or Facebook and then refactor the whole thing?

2) Language and Frameworks:

I have been a Microsoft developer for over 10 years, and as of the past couple of years, I have grown fond of open source languages, I learned some Ruby on Rails and PHP and I would like to stick to them (open source languages) for this project. Thinking about the easy of use, rapid development, and future growth of the application (which includes hiring developers, etc) which languages would you suggest?

3) Database:

Again, SQL server being from Microsoft is an easy pick for me, sticking to the open source concept, would MySQL be the best option?

I think this covers it. If there are any questions, please ask away and I will edit the original post to include whatever I have missed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a small project I would recommend using that as your reference point. That forces your hand on some decisions I think.

1. The API might be overkill if you're not immediately ready to do mobile work. Plus you can always re-factor the code to hide behind a service layer later.
2. Pick the language you like coding in. In my opinion some of the differences between languages only start to appear at massive scale. For example, many big companies with lots of data are moving away from Ruby. But don't worry about that now. Just find a language that makes you happy so you can get something going fast.
3. Since you're on a budget, I'd go with MySQL. It's not a huge learning curve if you come from SQL Server. Lots of concepts - and even syntax - transfer over well.

In my opinion to get an idea off the ground you need to make it fun. That means fun/interesting languages and tools *and* keeping things simple.

If you start to have tons of success you can always hire people smarter than you to help out. =)

Comment: Thanks @ryan1234, I appreciated your answer. Although I don't think it is a small project, I do think that doing what I like and having fun is the way to go. I will wait to see if there are other ideas, and they will pick the best answer. Thanks again!